# How add horizontal scrolling in GridView for windows 10 universal app?

Tags: c#, xaml, scroll, windows-10, win-universal-app

I using GridView with SemanticZoom in my windows 10 universal app. This my simple test code:

```
<SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <GridView x:Name="Nums" >
            <GridViewItem>1</GridViewItem>
            <GridViewItem>2</GridViewItem>
            <GridViewItem>3</GridViewItem>
            ...
            <GridViewItem>299</GridViewItem>
            <GridViewItem>300</GridViewItem>
        </GridView>
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>


    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <ListView>
            <ListViewItem x:Name="Group1">1-100</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem x:Name="Group2">101-200</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem x:Name="Group3">201-300</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
</SemanticZoom>
```

If I change the page size appears vertical scrolling. But I need horizontal scrolling. I try add in my GridView

```
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
```

but this not work. How add horizontal scrolling in GridView?

Comment: At first glance that looks correct but I guess it's not if you're here lol. Might try adding `ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True"`

Comment: I try this code for Windows 10. If  I create projects for windows 8.1 -horizontal scrolling showing.

Answer (score 2):

I decided my question. This working code:

```
  <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView >
        <GridView  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto">

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid  Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            ....
    </SemanticZoom>
```